# libc version conflict when included in library

Tags: libc

I have a C project that uses libc, and I need to compile it into a static library that will be added later to a different project.

My question is: what will happen if the second project (the one that will use my library) is already using a differnt version of libc? Will this fail during linkage? And if so, how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: This depends on the libc being used. Please specify which one you use.

Comment: Hi Florian. I am not exactly sure... I am using Keil (uvision version 5.25.2.0) for compiling. I think Keil uses 'armlib' instead o standard libc.